# Agility Pack AggregateException

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, html-agility-pack

I can capture a website with the following code, but I get the following error when I try to use the HTML Agility Pack as shown in the second code snippet.

```
    string strURL = " http://www.donbest.com/mlb/odds/money-lines/";

        try
        {
            WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(strURL);
            StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            string strLine;

            while ((strLine = stream.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (strLine.Length > 0)
                    sb.Append(strLine + Environment.NewLine);
            }
            stream.Close();
             m_strSite = sb.ToString();
             currentSiteData = m_strSite;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string exStr = ex.ToString();
        }
```

And here is the Agility Pack code.

```
string siteUrl = "  http://www.donbest.com/mlb/odds/money-lines";
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        var doc = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => web.Load(siteUrl));

       foreach (HtmlNode table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table/tbody"))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Found: " + table.Id);
            foreach (HtmlNode row in table.SelectNodes("tr"))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(row.InnerText.ToString());
                string tempRow = row.InnerHtml;
                foreach (HtmlNode cell in row.SelectNodes("th|td"))
                {
                    string tempCell = cell.InnerText;
                }
            }
        }
```

I get the error on the web.Load line.

System.AggregateException
"One or more errors occurred. (An error occurred while sending the request.)"

> System.AggregateException
>     HResult=0x80131500
>     Message=One or more errors occurred. (An error occurred while sending the request.)
>     Source=System.Private.CoreLib
>     StackTrace:
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
>      at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.Get(Uri uri, String method, String path, HtmlDocument doc, IWebProxy proxy, ICredentials creds)
>      at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.LoadUrl(Uri uri, String method, IWebProxy proxy, ICredentials creds)
>      at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.Load(Uri uri, String method)
>      at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.Load(String url)
>      at MLB_2019_Wagers.Views.MainPage.d__2.MoveNext() in C:\Projects2019\MLB_2019_Wagers\MLB_2019_Wagers\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs:line 233

Inner Exception 1:
HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.

Inner Exception 2:
COMException: The text associated with this error code could not be found.

'': Invalid characters found.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string siteUrl = "http://www.donbest.com/mlb/odds/money-lines";
var doc = web.Load(siteUrl);
```

There's extra space in your siteUrl string, and I don't think you need to start a new task for this.